# Trouble in ActiveX multi-thread invoke javascript callback routine

Tags: javascript, callback, activex, atl

everyone. 
I'm get some trouble in ActiveX programming with ATL. I try to make a activex which can async-download files from http server to local folder and after download it will invoke javascript callback function.
My solution: run a thread M to monitor download thread D, when D is finish the job, M is going to terminal themself and invoke IDispatch inferface to call javascript function.
******************************** THERE IS MY CODE: ********************************

```
/* javascript code */
funciton download() {
   var xfm = new ActiveXObject("XFileMngr.FileManager.1");
   xfm.download(
    'http://somedomain/somefile','localdev:\\folder\localfile',function(msg){alert(msg);});
}

/* C++ code */

// main routine
STDMETHODIMP CFileManager::download(BSTR url, BSTR local, VARIANT scriptCallback)
{
    CString csURL(url);
    CString csLocal(local);

    CAsyncDownload download;
    download.Download(this, csURL, csLocal, scriptCallback);

    return S_OK;
}

// parts of CAsyncDownload.h
typedef struct tagThreadData {
    CAsyncDownload* pThis;
} THREAD_DATA, *LPTHREAD_DATA;

class CAsyncDownload :
    public IBindStatusCallback
{
private:
    LPUNKNOWN pcaller;
    CString csRemoteFile;
    CString csLocalFile;
    CComPtr<IDispatch> spCallback;
public:
    void onDone(HRESULT hr);

    HRESULT Download(LPUNKNOWN caller, CString& csRemote, CString& csLocal, VARIANT callback);

    static DWORD __stdcall ThreadProc(void* param);
};
// parts of CAsyncDownload.cpp
void CAsyncDownload::onDone(HRESULT hr) {
    if(spCallback) {
        TRACE(TEXT("invoke callback function\n"));
        CComVariant vParams[1];
        vParams[0] = "callback is working!";

        DISPPARAMS params = { vParams, NULL, 1, 0 };

        HRESULT hr = spCallback->Invoke(0,
            IID_NULL,
            LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT,
            DISPATCH_METHOD,
            &params, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if(FAILED(hr)) {
            CString csBuffer;
            csBuffer.Format(TEXT("invoke failed, result value: %d \n"),hr);
            TRACE(csBuffer);
        }else {
            TRACE(TEXT("invoke was successful\n"));
        }
    }
}

HRESULT CAsyncDownload::Download(LPUNKNOWN caller, CString& csRemote, CString& csLocal, VARIANT callback) {
    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

    csRemoteFile = csRemote;
    csLocalFile = csLocal;
    pcaller = caller;

    switch(callback.vt){
        case VT_DISPATCH:
        case VT_VARIANT:{
            spCallback = callback.pdispVal;
        }
        break;
        default:{
            spCallback = NULL;
        }
    }

    LPTHREAD_DATA pData = new THREAD_DATA;
    pData->pThis = this;

    // create monitor thread M
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadProc, (void*)(pData), 0, NULL);

    if(!hThread) {
        delete pData;
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    }

    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(hThread);

    CoUninitialize();

    return S_OK;
}


DWORD __stdcall CAsyncDownload::ThreadProc(void* param) {
    LPTHREAD_DATA pData = (LPTHREAD_DATA)param;

    // here, we will create http download thread D
    // when download job is finish, call onDone method;

    pData->pThis->onDone(S_OK);

    delete pData;

    return 0;
}
```

************************** CODE FINISH ******************************** 
OK, above is parts of my source code, if I call onDone method in sub-thread,
I will get OLE ERROR(-2147418113 (8000FFFF)    Catastrophic failure.). 
Did I miss something? please help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

IE's JavaScript engine is single-threaded and so is ATL's event raising code.  Have the subthread post a message to the thread in which the ActiveX is created (e.g. to the handle of the ActiceX window if there is one), then raise the event.

Comment: He beat me to it... COM works generally on one thread. There are other ways to set up the other threads so that you can use COM on them and then marshall the objects across threads, but the approach mentioned here is a lot simpler (and I don't actually know how to do the other, I just know it can be done).

Comment: Thanks, Jiang. It's invisible ActiveX object, it will communicate with hardware quietly, so I create a thread to waiting signal, if there come signals it will invoke script callback function, It's what I want. If ActiveX main thread waiting reading thread finish, it will block browser response, I think maybe IWebBrowser2(to get script invoke interface) or COM connection points(COM event) will work, I will try it.

Comment: I found a topic: author do a example to call javascript in same thread and he said: CoMarshalInterface and CoUnmarshalInterface can figure out multithread script callback, does it same as Taxilian's idea?

Comment: Ok, guys. I use API CoMarshalInterface and CoUnmarshalInterface figure out my question: Create IStream object as thread parameter and retrieve COM interface in work thread and invoke method. It's work fine.